# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar una cadena de texto con una lista en Python?

Tags: python, string, lista

Descripción del problema:

Lo que pasa es que al querer mostrar el contenido de la variable "Cuantas", me aparece el siguiente error:

> cuantas = input("¿Cuantas tareas tienes de " + tareas + "?: ")
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

La variable "tareas" si contiene un dato de una lista

Lo mismo me pasa cuando quiero concatenar la variable "cual" en la variable "fecha"

```
print("=======================================")
print("\n ADMINISTRADOR DE TAREAS ESCOLARES \n")
print("=======================================\n")

materias = []
tareas = []
cuantas= []
cual= []
fechas = []

nombre = input ("¿Cual es tu nombre?: ")
while True:
    print(nombre+''' ¿Que desea hacer?: ")
1.-Anotar tareas.
2.-Revisar tareas pendientes.
3.-Revisar las tareas ya realizadas
------------------------------------''')
    desision = int(input('Preione el numero correspondiente: '))

    if desision == 1:
        num_totmat = int(input('Escriba la cantidad de materias que desea almacenar: '))
        for i in range(num_totmat):
            materias+=[input('Dime el nombre de esta materia: ')]
        tareas += [input("¿De que materia tienes tarea?: ")]
        cuantas = input("¿Cuantas tareas tienes de "+ tareas + "?: ")
        cual += [input("Escribe el titulo de esta tarea:  ")]
        fecha = input("Escribe la fecha de entrega de la tarea de " + cual + ": ")


    if desision == 2:
        print("Ahora esta consultando sus tareas pendientes")

    if desision==3:
        print("Esta consultando sus tareas ya realizadas")

    else:
        print("Esa opcion no existe. Por favor elija una opcion correcta.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres mostrar el contenido de una lista en forma de un string lo puedes hacer con el método `.join()`.

```
print(",".join(tareas))
```

Como recomendación utiliza los *f-string*, con eso te evitas varios problemas.

```py
input(f"¿Cuantas tareas tienes de {','.join(tareas)} ?: ")
```

A su vez, en lugar de hacer `tareas += [input("¿De que materia tienes tarea?: ")]` puedes usar `append()` de esta forma se entiende mejor lo que haces.

```py
tarea = input("¿De que materia tienes tarea?: ")
tareas.append(tarea)

#o
# tareas.append(input("¿De que materia tienes tarea?: "))
```

Lo mismo para el resto.